# Assignment statement for two dimensional list

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, initialization, variable-assignment

My program needs to inspect every element in a two-dimensional array and populate a new array with the countNeigh(x,y) of the old array [countNeigh returns the number of living neighbors in the old animal array]

I initialise the new array as a copy of the current/old array and use two `for` loops to inspect each individual element as well as populate the new array:

```
newAnimalArr = isAnimalArr
for x in range(len(isAnimalArr)):
    for y in range(len(isAnimalArr[x])):
        newAnimalArr[x][y] = countNeigh(x,y)
```

The code above populates the newAnimalArr with incorrect values. I am 98% sure that this is not an error in the countNeigh(x,y) function because when altering the code slightly(as shown below) the newAnimalArr has the correct values.

```
newAnimalArr = []

for x in range(len(isAnimalArr)):
    rowArr = []
    for y in range(len(isAnimalArr[x])):
        rowArr.append(countNeigh(x,y))
    newAnimalArr.append(rowArr)
```

-What is the issue with the first section of code? The initialising of the array? or the assignment statement for each element?

I have previously read that the initialising of a two-dimensional array `q = [[None]*5]*4` is one array that is referenced multiple times (which causes the assignment of a single element to propagate through all duplications of that single array); even if a similar issue occurs in my array then there should also be an issue with the assignment statement `newAnimalArr[x][y] = countNeigh(x,y)` because the initialising is done simply to duplicate the dimensions of the current/old array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll hedge my bets on the fact that `countNeigh` references the original `isAnimalArr` for its computation. Am I right? Because, that will explain your wrong answer. Why? Because of this line:

```
newAnimalArr = isAnimalArr
```

You make a *reference copy*, not an *actual copy*. This means that `newAnimalArr` and `isAnimalArr` refer to the *same* array. So, any modifications made to `newAnimalArr` affect the original. For example:

```
In [1028]: x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Assign `x` to `y`, as you have done.

```
In [1029]: y = x
```

Compare the `ids`, they're the same.

```
In [1032]: id(x) == id(y)
Out[1032]: True
```

Modify `y`:

```
In [1033]: y[0][1] = 234567
```

The change is seen in `x` too.

```
In [1034]: x
Out[1034]: [[1, 234567, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

---

If you want to avoid this, you need to make a copy.

```
import copy
newAnimalArr = copy.copy(isAnimalArr)
```

Now, changes made to `newAnimalArr` have no effect on `isAnimalArr`, so `countNeigh` should return the right values with respect to `isAnimalArr` which is not modified at any point of time.